# regexp in javascript to get all of the fields of an array which start with a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var myArr=["test1.nameA", "test1.nameB", "test2.nameC", "test2.nameA"];
```

I want to get those strings which start with "test1."

I have tried the following:

1)could you please let me know why I'm still getting all of the strings in the array?

```
   for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            if ((myArr[i]).search(new RegExp("test1") != -1)) {
                console.log(myArr[i]);
            }
        }
```

but this one is returning all elements! What am I doing wrong?

2) Also is it possible to check that it only starts with "test1" not just contains!

**Updated the question:**

```
myArr=["test1.nameA", "test1.nameB", "test2.nameC", "test2.nameA"]; 
var input="test1"; 
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) { 
if(myArr[i].search( new RegExp (/input/)) != -1) { 
     console.log(myArr[i]); 
} 
}
```

Thanks! Please let me know if you need more clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing the value of `new RegExp("test1")`

```
if ((myArr[i]).search(new RegExp("test1") != -1)) {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And `new RegExp("test1")` will never equal `-1`, which mean your test is always true.

This is what you need:

```
var myArr=["test1.nameA", "test1.nameB", "test2.nameC", "test2.nameA"];

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
   if ((myArr[i]).search(new RegExp("test1")) != -1) {
      console.log(myArr[i]);
   }
}
```

Or better still, to avoid creating a new RegExp every time around the loop:

```
var myArr=["test1.nameA", "test1.nameB", "test2.nameC", "test2.nameA"];
var rex = new RegExp("test1");

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
   if ((myArr[i]).search(rex) != -1) {
      console.log(myArr[i]);
   }
}
```

Additionally, `.search()` returns the position that the expression is found in the string, and -1 if it isn't found. So when it returns zero, that means it's found at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep only the values that match a regexp using `Array.prototype.filter` like this:

```
myArr.filter(function (i) { return /^test1\./.test(i); })
```

And to check that something just beggins with a string use `/^string/`. Note the `^`

Comment: Thanks man I would prefer the mentioned pattern with newRegEXp ; I also updated my question; "test1" is an input and lets call it name! Do you knwo why my updated code is still returning -1 for all strings?

Comment: You don't need to call to new RegEx. Javascript has regex literals, just use them. And the regexp of the updated version is wrong. Nothing contains the "input" string.

Comment: This is the best answer. The one @Pasargad accepted is only "containing" not "starting with".

Answer (score 0):

You could just test the values against the same RegExp.

```
var myArr=["test1.nameA", "test1.nameB", "test2.nameC", "test2.nameA"];

var pattern = /^test1\./; // begins with test1 followed by a dot

for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if(pattern.test(myArr[i])) {
    console.log(myArr[i]);
  }
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/qilinohora/1/edit?js,console